# Does rails cache seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I wanted to seed some data in my rails API form a CSV file. So, I did the needful:

seed.rb

```rb
require 'CSV'

Meal.destroy_all
Vendor.destroy_all

CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('./db/vendordata.csv'), headers: false) do |r|
  Vendor.create! do |m|
    m.vendorname = r[0]
    m.email = r[1]
    m.phone_number = r[2]
    m.company_name = r[3]
    m.company_branch = r[4]
    m.password = r[5]
  end
end

CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('./db/meals.csv'), headers: false) do |r|
    Meal.create! do |m|
      m.vendor_id = r[0]
      m.name = r[1]
      m.desc = r[2]
      m.price = r[3]
      m.sample_alt = r[4]
      m.discount = r[5]
      m.class = r[6]
    end
end
```

However, when I first ran `rails db:seed`, I got an `SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error, which would have had to come from `Meals`... cause that has a `vendor_id`. I went and corrected the error in my CSV file, ran `rails db:seed` and still got the same error. Now I have emptied my `seed.rb`, and I still get that same error.

What I have tried:
I have run `Rails.cache.clear` in my console.
I reset my database.

Comment: No it's not cached

Comment: Could you shed more light?

Comment: What more light is there to shed really? Rails doesn't cache anything in `seeds.rb`, what makes you think it is doing any caching?

Comment: Well, it was returning the same errors from my first `db:seed` after I changed the cause of the error and even cleared the entire document.

Comment: That is not possible, you must be pointing to the wrong document or folder then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This likely has to do with your database randomly generated vendor_id.

Even though you are cleaning the database, the vendor_id internal counter doesn't reset (I'm assuming it's an auto-increment integer).

So if you had a Meal with **vendor_id = 3** for example, after deleting the data and seeding again, the vendor_ids would start with, for example, 4, and your Meal model would reference non-existent ids. That's why you get a foreign key failure.

Try actually destroying your entire database and building again, instead of just deleting the data.

Alternatively, as pointed out, you can run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE foo_bars AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')` to reset the auto_increment.

Comment: Yh... this worked thanks. But I reset the auto_increment of the table with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE foo_bars AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')`... if you could add this o your answer for future references.